# Find limit $\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\bar z}{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Evaluate $\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\bar z}{z}$ where $z=x+iy$

My try:

$$\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\bar z}{z}=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{x-iy}{x+iy}$$

$$=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{(x-iy)(x-iy)}{(x+iy)(x-iy)}$$

$$=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{x^2-y^2-2ixy}{x^2+y^2}$$

$$=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}-\frac{2ixy}{x^2+y^2}$$

I can't solve it from here. My teacher says that the limit doesn't exist but I don't know how & why. Please help me solve this question

Answer (score 7):

You don't need simplify
$$\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\bar z}{z}=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{x-iy}{x+iy}$$
consider for $x=0$ and $y=0$. Then you have different values.

Comment: That's a correct observation!

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Try to approach the origin along the real axis, and then along the imaginary axis (i.e. take first $z = t,\; t\in \mathbb{R}$ and let $t \to 0$, and then take $z = it, \; t\in\mathbb{R}$ and let $t \to 0)$.  Do you get the same limit?

Comment: Very nice hint!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, starting form your step, the limit

$$\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\bar z}{z}=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}-\frac{2ixy}{x^2+y^2}$$

doesn't exist indeed

- for $y=0$ $$\implies \frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}-\frac{2ixy}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{x^2}{x^2}-\frac{0}{x^2}=1\implies \lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\bar z}{z}=1$$
- for $x=y$ $$\implies \frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}-\frac{2ixy}{x^2+y^2}=0-\frac{2ix^2}{2x^2}=-i\implies \lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\bar z}{z}=-i$$

As noticed by Nosrati, we don't need to simplify the original expression to obtain the same result.

Comment: Nice and complete as always, gimusi! =)

Comment: why did you take $y=x$ instead of $x=0$ in second point?

Comment: @jeanneclement For fun! Why not? It works!

Comment: @jeanneclement When we deal with limit of several variables we can approach the point along infinitely many paths. A necessary condition for the existence is that the limit is the same for any path. In that way we have shown that the paths with y=0 and x=y give different limits and therefore the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: @Sobi: See Nosrati's answer he tells take $x=0$ & $y=0$ to approach the origin as $z\to 0$. Now tell be can I always take  $y=0$ & $x=y$ ??

Comment: @jeanneclement Both methods work. In my answer, I also took $x=0$ and then $y=0$. But that does not matter really in this case! I'm not sure what you mean when you ask if you can *always* take those paths. The paths that work are somewhat dependent on the limit you are dealing with. The point is that we managed to show that the limit is different when you approach the origin via different paths - hence the limit does not exist.

Comment: @jeanneclement Also in Nostrati way for x=y we have $\frac{1-i}{1+i}=\frac{1-1-2i}{2}=-i$

Answer (score 0):

Just a correction to a comment. Limit does exists, but limit along real component is different than limit along imaginary component. Hence function is not continuous. Right? I wonder if epsilon-delta form of limit might help prove no limit exists.

Answer (score 0):

Polar coordinates;

$z=re^{i\phi}$, $r\not =0.$

$\overline{z}=re^{-i\phi}$.

$\dfrac{\overline{z}}{z}= e^{i(-2\phi)}.$

Approaching $0$ , i.e.

$r \rightarrow 0$, along any $\phi =$const,

yields a different point $P(e^{i(-2\phi)})$ on the unit circle in the complex plane.